# What is the origin of this Batman comic book panel?

Tags: dc, batman, episode-identification

A comic book panel that circulates around social media from time to time features Batman kicking a criminal in the groin, where his loaded gun goes off.

[image: Batman kicks a guy]

It's kind of a hilarious image but I have no idea what its origin is. Where did this panel originate?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is [Batman: Jekyll & Hyde #4](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman:_Jekyll_and_Hyde_Vol_1_4)

[image]

For the record, the next panel is equally hilarious

Warning: NSFW (Gory)

> Ouch [image]

Comment: I don't think hilarious means what either you or the OP thinks it does...

Comment: @CGCampbell - Oh, come on. The guy shoots his own junk off. That's comedy ***gold***